# Check if WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup) is enabled or disabled via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, network-programming, wifi, wifi-protected-setup

Is it possible to check if the WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup) in a router is enabled or disabled via Powershell? 
When I run this command:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

I get the bssid and other information about the wifi networks nearby, but I also need to know if the WPS is enabled or disabled. I would be happy if the response would be true or false.

If this is not possible via Powershell, is there another possible way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.getwpsconfigurationasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-devices-wifi-wifiadapter-getwpsconfigurationasync(windows-devices-wifi-wifiavailablenetwork) descrbibes an UWP method. You can call UWP methods from Powershell 5.1, but it requires a lot of extra work (you also need to write custom code which uses reflection to handle the async com results). Hardly worth the trouble...